# Concurrent Thread Manager

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I have the following implementation of a concurrent thread manager

```
newtype Query = Query String

type ThreadWorker = (Query, ThreadStatus)
data ThreadStatus = Running | Finished | Threw IOException

newtype ThreadManager = Manager (MVar (M.Map ThreadId (MVar ThreadWorker)
```

I want to write `manageWorkers :: ThreadManager -> IO ()` that traverses the `Map` and looks at the `ThreadStatus` of the `ThreadWorker`.

If the `ThreadWorker` is finished, then it is deleted from the `ThreadManager`. If an exception has been thrown, then it should be handled (print to stdout is fine for example purposes) and a new thread should be forked to process the query (assume the existance of a function `runQuery :: Query -> IO a`) and be added to the `ThreadManager`, else the thread is still running and should be left alone.

my first attempt at an implementation was:

```
manageWorkers :: ThreadManager -> IO ()
manageWorkers (Manager mgr) =
    modifyMVar mgr $ \m -> do
        m' <- M.traverseWithKey manageWorker m
        return (m', ())
where manageWorker :: ThreadId -> MVar ThreadWorker -> IO (MVar ThreadWorker)
      manageWorker tid wkr = tryTakeMVar wkr >>= \mwkr ->
          case mwkr of
               Just (_, Finished) -> undefined -- need to delete this finished ThreadWorker
               Just (q, Threw e ) -> do
                   putStrLn ("[ERROR] " ++ show e)
                   tid' <- forkIO $ runQuery q
                   undefined -- need to add new ThreadWorker
               Just r -> newMVar r
               _ -> newEmptyMVar
```

but then I got stuck, it doesnt seem possible to delete or add from/to the `ThreadManager` while in `manageWorker`. I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I want from a `traverse`-like function.

Is it possible to implement this `manageWorkers` function using my `ThreadManager` or is there a better abstraction out there?

EDIT: at ThomasM.DuBuisson's suggestion to use a fold, I now have the following

```
manageWorkers (Manager mgr) =
    modifyMVar mgr $ \m ->
    return (M.foldrWithKey manageWorker M.empty m, ())
where manageWorker :: ThreadId -> MVar ThreadWorker -> M.Map ThreadId (MVar ThreadWorker)
                      -> IO (M.Map ThreadId (MVar ThreadWorker))
      manageWorker tid wkr ts = tryTakeMVar wkr >>= \mwkr ->
          case mwkr of
              Just (q, Threw e) -> do
                  putStrLn ("[ERROR] " ++ show e)
                  wkr' <- newEmptyMVar
                  tid' <- forkIO $ runQuery q
                  return $ M.insert tid' wkr' ts
              Just (_, Running) -> return $ M.insert tid wkr
              _ -> return ts
```

the only problem is that obviously `manageWorker`'s signature does not work with `M.foldrWithKey`. I need a `M.foldrWithKeyM :: Monad m => (k -> a -> b -> m b) -> b -> M.Map k a -> m b` but such a thing does not exist, and I'm having trouble composing it myself.

Obviously I can use `unsafePerformIO` to escape the IO monad and satisfy the compiler, but I would only use that as a last resort. Is this a situation in which it makes sense to use `unsafePerformIO`?

Comment: If you `takeMVar mgr` then you should be able to traverse over the workers and `putMVar mgr newMgr` without an issue.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: isn't `modifyMVar` just an abstraction over a `takeMVar/putMvar` pattern?

Comment: Yes, but if you are having trouble seeing how to pass the modified state along to each manageWorker (scan/fold style) for use in modifyMVar, then perhaps explicitly using the MVar to save state will get you started.  Notice this is a comment and not intended as a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you question is irrelevant to concurrency.
You just want to traverse a map, meanwhile, delete some keys from the map or insert some keys in the map and perform some `IO` actions.
The problem is `traverseWithKey` cannot delete keys from the map or insert keys in the map, `foldrWithKey` cannot perform `IO` actions.
You need a `M.foldrWithKeyM :: Monad m => (k -> a -> b -> m b) -> b -> M.Map k a -> m b`
Indeed, such a thing does not exist. But if you look at the documentation of `foldrWithKey`, which states:

```
foldrWithKey f z == foldr (uncurry f) z . toAscList.
```

We can guess such `M.foldrWithKeyM` can be composed if we replcae `foldr` by `foldM`.

The following is my solution.

```
manageWorkers :: ThreadManager -> IO ()
manageWorkers (Manager mgr) = 
    modifyMVar mgr $ \m -> do
        m' <- foldM manageWorker m (M.toList m)
        return (m', ())
  where manageWorker :: M.Map ThreadId (MVar ThreadWorker) -> (ThreadId, MVar ThreadWorker) -> IO (M.Map ThreadId (MVar ThreadWorker))
        manageWorker ts (tid, wkr) = tryTakeMVar wkr >>= \mwkr ->
            case mwkr of
                 Just (_, Finished) -> return $ M.delete tid ts -- need to delete this finished ThreadWorker
                 Just (q, Threw e ) -> do
                       putStrLn ("[ERROR] " ++ show e)
                       wkr' <- newEmptyMVar
                       tid' <- forkIO $ runQuery q
                       return $ M.insert tid' wkr' ts -- need to add new ThreadWorker
                 _ -> return ts
```